# assert conditions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, assertions

I've write a junit test with eclipse ,
to check the Gui component status ,I use assert : `textfield.assert("expected message")`
i'm searching how to get the error message printed by assert 
the message saying that the expected text doesn't match th typed text is printed in the eclipse console
I like to get this message to generate a report
is there an easy mean, my be a junit method ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work out as something like:

```
assert("Bad output", expectedResults);
```

I'd use:

```
assertEquals("Bad output for # attempt", expectedResults, obtainedResults);
```

though

Comment: thanks, 
where should I say print the message(displayed by assert in eclipse console) in this file(my created file) ?

Comment: please someone could give me an idea?